# Remove first 3 columns from `ls`?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, cut

If I do `ls -o` I get

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 louise     347967 Aug 28  2017 Screenshot from 2017-08-28 09-33-01.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 louise     377739 Aug 29  2017 Screenshot from 2017-08-29 10-39-49.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 louise     340682 Aug 29  2017 Screenshot from 2017-08-29 10-40-02.png
```

I really want to remove the first 3 columns, so I get

```
347967 Aug 28  2017 Screenshot from 2017-08-28 09-33-01.png
377739 Aug 29  2017 Screenshot from 2017-08-29 10-39-49.png
340682 Aug 29  2017 Screenshot from 2017-08-29 10-40-02.png
```

`ls` can't do this, it seems. There are other questions here at SO about removing multiple columns, but not from the beginning.

Comment: You should look at [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: *Why* do you want to remove those columns?  If it's to provide a somewhat anonymised listing to give to another user, then you could just use `cut`.  But if you intend to parse the information there, then don't start with `ls` - it's not meant for that!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ls` is an interactive tool, whose output is [not supposed to be parsed](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Consider using an alternative tool such as `stat` (GNU version recommended):

```
stat -c '%s %y %n' *
```

The output isn't quite the same but you have full control over the format. `stat --help` gives more information about the possible format sequences.

With GNU stat you can also use `--printf` to add escape characters such as newlines or tabs in the format string, to make parsing easier:

```
stat --printf '%s\t%Y\t%n\n' *
```

`%Y` (last modification, seconds since Epoch) is more readily suited to parsing than `%y` (human-readable).

This would still break in cases where the filename contained a newline, so depending on how you plan on using this information, you may want to use a `\0` instead of a `\n` at the end of the format string and process records terminated with a null-byte instead of a newline.

Alternatively, you may find it easier to just loop through the files and call `stat` on them one by one, extracting whatever you need:

```
for file in *; do
    read -r size modified name < <(stat '%s %Y %n' "$file")
    # do whatever with $size, $modified and $name here
done
```

Assuming you go with the loop-based approach, you can convert the date to any format you want using `date`, for example:

```
date -d @"$modified" +'%b %d %H:%m'
```

Comment: `%y` is a bit closer to `ls`'s date format, but still very odd. `2017-05-15 11:02:42.388552115 +0200`. Is there a way to get `ls` style date format with `stat`?

Comment: The date format in `ls` is not well-defined, as mentioned in the article I linked to at the start of my question. I edited my answer to show how you could use GNU `date` to help convert the format.

Comment: Can you show filesize in megabytes with `stat`?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz the size will be reported in bytes, but you can use one of the approaches mentioned here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346902/67817 to convert `$size` to whatever format you like.